# real- time currency converter Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, currency, converters

I'm trying to make a simple currency conversion application . here I am parsing json

```
static func fetchJson(key: String = "USD", completion: @escaping (ExchangeRates) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/\(String(describing: key))") else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let safeData = data else {return}
        
        do {
            let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(ExchangeRates.self, from: safeData)
            completion(results)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

then I get a dictionary looks like:

```
"rates": {
        "USD": 1,
        "AED": 3.67,
        "AFN": 105,
        "ALL": 107.39,
        "AMD": 481.52,
        "ANG": 1.79,
        "AOA": 538.31,
         ..... etc
```

this is how the structure in which the data is stored looks like

```
struct ExchangeRates: Codable {
    let rates: [String: Double] 
}
```

in the *ViewController* I have created an object that has the type of ExchangeRates struct and call the *func fetchJson* in *viewDidLoad* and save the result in *finalCurrencies*

```
var finalCurrencies: ExchangeRates?
```

then I  created a tableview with the number of cells equal to

> finalCurrencies.rates.count

tableViewCell has a *currencyLabel* with currency name (*finalCurrencies.rates.key*) and *currencyTextField* with currency value (*finalCurrencies.rates.value*)

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let currencyFetched = finalCurrencies {
            return currencyFetched.rates.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
            if let currencyFetched = finalCurrencies {
                cell.currencyLabel.text = Array(currencyFetched.rates.keys)[indexPath.row]
                cell.currencyTextField.accessibilityIdentifier = Array(currencyFetched.rates.keys)[indexPath.row]
                let selectedRate = Array(currencyFetched.rates.values)[indexPath.row]
                cell.currencyTextField.text = "\(selectedRate)"
                return cell
          }
       }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

And that's what I get in the end as a result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oiG8.png)

**QUESTION**: I need to make it so that when the value in the textfield for a certain currency changes, the values of the other currencies change in real- time. as a live google currency converter. I should also be able to switch between currencies and change their values, while also the values of other currencies should change. also how to make it so that with each new number an existing dictionary *finalCurrencies* is used and not a *func fetchJson* ?

I suppose that I should use this *func textField* (so that the textField reacts to each addition of a number).

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
```

}

I'm a beginner and I've been thinking about this for a few days now and I don't know how to do it.thanks in advance.

Comment: One solution will be to always getValue for 1 and when you get the results you can actually multiply it with the entered number. Also, you can just clear out the dictionary and replace it with new values from your function which will make it real time.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to calculate the ratio of the change for the currency which had its value modified, you'll then just map the values of the dictionary with that ratio:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Double {
     mutating func applyChange(of currency: Key, with newValue: Value) {
             guard
                newValue != .zero,
                let oldValue = self[currency],
                oldValue != newValue,
                oldValue != .zero
        else { return }
             
        let ratio = 1.0 + ((newValue - oldValue) / oldValue)
        indices.forEach { values[$0] *= ratio }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I've understood you correctly, I believe this would work.

Each time the user adjusts the value in the textField you'd loop through your rates dictionary, calculate the new rate and return an updated dictionary.

If I've misunderstood your goal please let me know and I'll do my best to assist :)

```
struct Converter {
    
    let exchangeRates: [String: Double] = [
        "USD": 1,
        "AED": 3.67,
        "AFN": 105,
        "ALL": 107.39,
        "AMD": 481.52,
        "ANG": 1.79,
        "AOA": 538.31
    ]
    
    func convert(_ amount: String) -> [String: Double] {
        
        var newRates = [String: Double]()
        
        exchangeRates.forEach { (code, value) in
            if let amount = Double(amount) {
                newRates[code] = value * amount
            }
        }
        
        return newRates
    }
    
}

let converter = Converter()
let userInput = "10.00"

print(converter.convert(userInput))
```

Comment: You're just mapping the values of the dictionary here.

Comment: 'convert()' would be used to accept the newly input value from the user and calculate the amounts for each country based on the exchange rate for that country, without altering the original exchange rates that were fetched. This is what was asked.

Comment: Your solution is more elegant but it doesn't mean that my answer is incorrect. You also don't need to be condescending.

Comment: It’s not a matter of elegance, in your answer you don’t take into account at all for which currency the change of price happened hence by what ratio other currencies shall change their value in proportion.

Comment: You're correct. I wasn't trying to provide a complete solution to the problem that was presented. @iOSPrincess ends their question by telling us they're a beginner. Personally, I don't think that spoon-feeding the solution is the best approach to teaching someone. This isn't to say that you shouldn't have provided the solution, it's me explaining why I didn't provide everything in mine.